# AJAX (JQuery) Returning Error Unexpectedly

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, syntax-error

I have this Jquery AJAX request to process the creation of Word documents (using [PHPWord](http://phpword.codeplex.com/)). The reports are processed and, as far as I am aware, I should not get an error. Whilst the reports are processed, I cannot get the 'data' response from the page, which returns the processed file's name which is needed to provide download links.

The AJAX request looks like this (it is based upon list items with the class 'selected'):

```
$('.selectionList.unprocessed li.selected').each(function(index) {
    params = 'reportNo=' + ($(this).index() + 1);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'word/export.php',
        data: params,
        dataType: 'script',
        type: 'post',
        success: function(data) { 
            increaseProgressBar();
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            increaseProgressBar(); 
            alert('failure ' + textStatus + ' and ' + errorThrown); 
        }
    });
});
```

increaseProgressBar() just increases the width of the coloured part of a progress bar.

The errors I get in the alert boxes are either:

> failure parsererror and SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

or (both are received seemingly randomly)

> failure parsererror and SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

I attempted to post to this page using a form and that worked fine and the page echoed the correct response.

Comment: You know, you can get rid of all quotes around ajax methods.

Comment: Check your `dataType`, it doesn't look like you actually want `script`

Comment: @elclanrs I have fixed that but I get the same errors (I don't think it really matters)

Comment: `if ($templateNo < 0)
{
    $template = $_SESSION['data']['default']['templates'][-($templateNo)];
} ... 
` can be writte as `$template = $_SESSION['data']['default']['templates'][abs($templateNo)];`

Comment: @jprofitt ahhh how simple - that fixed it.

Comment: Please upvote his comment if it fixed your issue.

Comment: I tried but 'Users with less than 100 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You may self-answer in 6 hours. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple solution - I just need to change the `dataType` from `script` to `text` and the rest of it works fine.